# how to use 2 partitions in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I use sql and in my query i always use 1 partition
It looks like this:

```
select *
From people partition(x)
```

When i try to use another partition it fails..

Does somebody know how to add another partiton?
Using comma or and or with inside the partition brackets only gives the ora-00933 sql command not properly ended error

Comment: Please post the query you used where you tried to use multiple partitions **and** show us the error message.

Comment: ora-00933 sql command not properly ended error

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple partitions as a comma-separated list:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  people PARTITION(x, y)
```

Comment: When i try seperating by commas it gives me: ora-00933 sql command not properly ended :(

Comment: @yogy partiton or partition?

Comment: Whoops, sorry didn't notice that i wrote partiton here. In my code it's the correct partition

Comment: Until 21c the [partition_extension_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) do **not** allow to specify more than one partiton...

Comment: Well... that's a shame :( can you think of a workaround maybe? Cause not using partitions is very slow..

Comment: Pretty simple workaround with `UNION ALL` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474515/how-to-select-data-from-multiple-partitions-in-oracle-table)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber thanks :)